# Is there a setting or plugin to make notepad++ hide tabbar when only one tab is opened?

Tags: notepad++, tabs

I have looked through the list of preferences (although for now I have a slightly outdated version, 7.3.3) and through the list of plugins and haven't found such an option. I'd like to be sure that I haven't overlooked that before creating an issue at GitHub, so please let me know if there's a way to configure such a behaviour.

PS I've created an [issue](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3989) but it never got response.

Comment: Go to Settings > Preferences > General > Tab Bar > Hide

Comment: @Biswa that hides tab bar permanently, not only when there's 1 tab